# Looking for an (embeddable) programming language to execute untrusted code

Tags: security, sandbox

I'm making a programming game (like Robocode) where you can write an AI to play a game against other players' code. For this to work I have to be able to execute untrusted code which appears to be quite difficult.

I'm looking for a programming language to use for the AI's.
Requirements:

- can be run securely (sandboxed)

  - no access to system or any io except stdin/-out.
  - execution time and memory limited
- cross platform
- not too esoteric

I'd either run the code from python, or if that's not feasible, as a standalone executable (via an interpreter) and communicate via stdin/-out.